# Vb.net Custom sum formula not calculating when blank cell are present

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have two problems one is if I have empty cells it will not work and second that it does not calculate on tables when using sum column5 
 Thanks for any help provided

The Cinches is converting a string like 12'-3 1/16" to 147.0625 inches
 and the toNearest16th converts it back to a string closest to the nearest sixteen of an inch something like 12'-3 1/16" 
 the problem is when trying to sum the results using the conversion because if there is a blank cell I get an error
 Show me some love guys
 thanks again

```
Public Shared Function TotalSumToNearest(Nums As Object) As Object
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '** Demonstrates how to use an array(or range of multiple cells) as
    '   a function argument.
    '   Can be called with formulas such as =GetArray(A1:B5), GetArray(A1),
    '   or GetArray({1,2,3;4,5,6}).
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim Sum As Double, v As Object
    On Error GoTo Handler
    If IsArray(Nums) Then
        For Each v In Nums
            'If TypeOf v.Getvalue() Is ExcelEmpty Then

            'Else
            Sum = Sum + CDbl(CInches(v) / 12)
            'End If
        Next
    Else
        Sum = CDbl(Nums)
    End If
    TotalSumToNearest = toNearest16th(Sum * 12)
    Exit Function
Handler:
    ' GetArray = CVErr(2036)  'xlErrNum = 2036
End Function
```

I'm posting a working code just in case anyone can use it

```
 Public Shared Function Sum_ToNearest_16th(Values As Object) As Object
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '** Demonstrates how to use an array(or range of multiple cells) as
    '   a function argument.
    '   Can be called with formulas such as =GetArray(A1:B5), GetArray(A1),
    '   or GetArray({1,2,3;4,5,6}).
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim Sum As Double

    If IsArray(Values) Then

        For Each ObjectValue As Object In Values
            Dim DoubleValue As Double = 0

            If TypeOf ObjectValue Is String Then
               ' Dim rst As string=""

              DoubleValue = CDbl(CInches(ObjectValue))
               ' ObjectValue=rst
            ElseIf TypeOf ObjectValue Is Double
                DoubleValue = ObjectValue
            Else
                Double.TryParse(ObjectValue.ToString(), DoubleValue)
            End If

            Sum += DoubleValue

        Next ObjectValue

    Else
        Double.TryParse(Values.ToString(), Sum)
    End If

    Return to_Nearest_16th(Sum)
End Function
```

Comment: Assuming that (v) is the value that could be blank, you cannot convert a null or an empty string to a double so if v = "" or v ISNULL then the line SUm = SUm + CDbl(CInches(v) /12) will fail.

Comment: Got it, that's why I posted the question cause it fails

Comment: You only have a check if the object sent is an array.  You do not have any check for what the v value is.